# PHP ¿Como puedo mostrar en alert o toastr que el dato ya existe?

Tags: php, javascript

Como podria mostrar un mensaje que el dato ya existe para el usuario, el dato ya esta validado para que no repita,pero necesito mostrar al usuario. En este caso el campo que no debe repetir es solo un campo. El codigo de abajo es el modelo donde hace el insert. Antes hace un select para verificar si el dato ya existe, que funciona no guarda repetido, solo necesito mostrar el mensaje.

```
public function add($v0,$v1,$v2) {  
//Sentencia preparada.
$stmt = $this->conexion->prepare('SELECT descripcionlinea FROM lineasproducciones WHERE descripcionlinea=?');
//Ligamos parametros marcadores (?)
$stmt->bind_param('s',$v1);//s si es cadena y i si es integer.
//Ejecutar sentencia
$stmt->execute();
//Transfiere un conjunto de resultados desde una sentencia preparada
$stmt->store_result();
//Comprobamos si existe registro
if($stmt->num_rows > 0) { 
    //cerrar statement
    $stmt->close();
    //Mensaje
   echo "<script>alert('Datos Repetidos')</script>";
} else { 

    $stmt->close();
    //crear statement
    $stmt = $this->conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO lineasproducciones VALUES (?,?,?)');
    if ( false===$stmt ) {
       die('prepare() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($this->conexion->error));
    }
    //parametro a statement
    $rc= $stmt->bind_param('sss',$v0,$v1,$v2);
    if ( false===$rc ) {
       die('bind_param() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($this->conexion->error));
    }
    //ejecutar el query
    $rc= $stmt->execute();
    if ( false===$rc ) {
       die('execute() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($this->conexion->error));

    }
    //cerrar statement

    $stmt->close();
}
```

> Tambien uso Codigo Javascript

```
    //boton guardar 
    $('#guardar').on('click', function(){
    var v0 = $('#p0').val();
    var v1 = $('#p1').val();
    var v2 = $('#p2').val(); 
        if (v0.length>0 && v1.length>0 && v2.length>0) 
        { //valida requerido
            $('#mensaje').html('<p></p>');
            var parametros = $('#formAdd').serialize();     
                       $.ajax({  //envia POST a otro php
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'lineaproduccion.iud.php',
            data: parametros,
            success: function(data){
                 if(data.success == true ){   
           alert('true');
        } else {
           alert('false')
                    }
                var url = document.URL;
                location.href = url;
            }
        });
    } 
    else {
        toastr["warning"]("FALTAN ALGUNOS DATOS", "ATENCION");
    }
```

})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola alexis tu quieres que cuando esta repetido te llege una alerta en tu vista diciendo que el dato ya esta repetido? en ese caso te recomiendo devolver a tu ajax un success o un err asi condiciones si es success insertas y si es err pues te lanza un el toast o el alert 
si ha insertado data le retornas un succes y si no le retoras un error en tu ajax le pones algo as

```
    if(data == 'success'){
       alert("genial se inserto correactamente")
}else{
       alert("Algo salio mal") //o el toast
}
```

Comment: Te agradezco por responder, el mensaje me muestra, me muestra que algo salio mal si esta repetido el dato,  pero si el dato no esta repetido igual me sale el mensaje de algo salio mal en vez de genial se inserto correctamente.

Comment: le hecho un console log a los datos que envias ? tanto a los datos que recibes , osea a tu function(data)

Comment: <script>alert('Datos Repetidos')</script> me duvuelve esa linea si hay datos repetidos, esa linea esta en el modelo ,  pero no se porque me esta mostrando el alert como false cuando el dato no existe en la bd. Osea me esta devolviendo como falso en los 2 casos si existe o no datos en la base de datos.

Comment: Edite mi codigo de javascript para que lo veas.

Comment: no hay forma de probarlo, no lo tendras en github ? para ayudarte con el problema? claro si es que es posible